# How to handle a column which contains date , number, string values in Python Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, xlwings

I have a Input CSV file in which column A has only number values and Column B  contains Number , string and date . When i try to read this CSV file with pd.read_csv and write the data to excel file using to_excel() function ,the output excel file stores the Value of date, number as string values in column B (Note: In Excel the string values are placed at the  left side of the cell and number, date value are stored to the right side of the cell , but in my output excel file the date, number values are stored as string in left side of the cell). how to prevent this happening ?

File link:[file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16wVwAlxqGa_cu7h0Ng0yRGWeHulepaZZ)

sample Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv("input.csv",parse_dates=False,na_filter = False) 
print (data.dtypes)
data.to_excel('output.xlsx',sheet_name = 'sheet1',index=False,float_format=None)
```

output file issue:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cj8eG.png) (In column B marked cell have date , number values stored as string value)

Expected output:[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtL9i.png) (Marked cells have date , number values in left side of the cell)

Dtype:
A     int64 , 
B    object
dtype: object

Comment: Would you rather break them up into multiple columns of Date, number and string?

Comment: Could you please share what is the expected output?

Comment: @NYCCoder my requirement is to have date , number , string in single column so i don't want to break into multiple columns

Comment: @TuhinSharma i have updated the expected output

Comment: I dont think column value indentation has anything to do with pandas. Its an "excel veiwing" question IMO.

Comment: There's a way to do this by modifying cell format. See the documentation here: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html

Comment: @prabhaahar did you try below lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the xlwings solved the problem.
eg code:

```
    import xlwings as xw
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    df=pd.read_csv('asset_input.csv',encoding='cp1252',parse_dates=False,na_filter = False)
    app = xw.App(visible=False)
    book = xw.Book('e2.xlsm')
    sht = book.sheets('ASSET')
    sht.range('B9').options(index=False, header=False).value = df
    book.save()
    book.close()
    app.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

As I could understand , multiple fomating on same column is the the requirement here.

check if below lines work for you

```
# this will change all possible values into int
df['yourcolumn']= df['your column'].astype(int, errors='ignore')
# this will convert all possible values in date
df['yourcolumn'] = pd.to_datetime(df['yourcolumn'], format=%d%b%Y,errors='ignore')
print(pd.head())
```

Comment: i don't want to apply any format to date values because that column may have different date formats . eg: 
21/2/2021 ,
23/2/2020 01:12:33.
if i apply above code : df['yourcolumn'] = pd.to_datetime(df['yourcolumn'], format=%d%b%Y,errors='ignore') then output will have only 1 date format.

Comment: did you tried running without passing that parameter

Comment: i tried but the number , date values still stored as string value in the excel cell (i.e : date , number values are at the right side of the cell)